# Lotus Notes Connector run the agent from replica after IIOP connection

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

**I do have the following situation:**

- `"ScheduledJobs.nsf"` with the agent `"Worker"`
- The `"ScheduledJobs.nsf"` is replicated on three domino server: `DominoServer1`, `DominoServer2`, `DominoServer3`
- With the `Lotus Notes Connector` im able to establish a connections over `IIOP` to the Notes Database `"ScheduledJobs.nsf"` on `DominoServer1`. This connections is static configured.
- Because there is connections to the Notes database, im able to run the agent `"Worker"` on the Notes Database `"ScheduledJobs.nsf"` on `DominoServer1` over `Javascript`.

**What I would like to do is this:**

Sometimes, depending on the situation, I would like to run the Agent **"Worker"** from the replica. For example I would like to run the agent **"Worker"** on `DominoServer2` or `DominoServer3`.

**Problem:**

Due to the connection to the Notes Database over `IIOP` is static, im always connecting to the database `"ScheduledJobs.nsf"` on the `DominoServer1`.

**Question:**

Am I able to run the agent `"Worker"` after this `IIOP` connection on the replica?

---

**EDITED**

**My code for "RunWorkerOn2"**

```
Dim agent As NotesAgent
Dim sess As New NotesSession    
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument    
Dim item As NotesItem

Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase   
Set agent = sess.CurrentAgent

Call db.Open( "DominoServer2/ORGANIZATION", "ScheduledJobs.nsf" )
Set agent = db.GetAgent("Worker")

// Reason why im using 'run' insted of RunOnServer:
// https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO42549
If agent.Run() = 0 Then
    Print "SUCCESS"
Else
    Print "FAILED"
End If
```

Comment: You need to connect to the other server.

Comment: @umeli Is it possible to connect to the other server and open the same database to run the agent on the 'remote' DominoServer? Unfortunately I didn't achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this indireclty.

In the ScheduledJobs database that contains "Worker", add two new agents: "RunWorkerOn2" and "RunWorkerOn3".

In the code of the RunWorkerOn2 agent, add code to open ScheduledJobs.nsf on DominoServer2 and use NotesDatabase.GetAgent("Worker"). Then call NotesAgent.RunOnServer to run Worker on Dominoserver2.

Similarly, in the code of the RunWorkerOn3 agent, open ScheduledJobs.nsf on DominoServer3 and use NotesDatabas.GetAgent("Worker"). Then call NotesAgent.RunOnserver to run Worker on DominoServer3.

So this way, your connector still connects to DominoServer1, and it runs all of its agaengs on DominoServer1, but those agents in turn will run agents on DominoServer2 and DominoServer3.

Comment: Great - this could work, I will test it. Thank you. But one question: My connector is writing a notes document with some important information, on which the agent have to read these information and work with that. Lets say my connector creates a notes document on DominoServer1, but the agent have to run on on DominoServer2 - do than I have to wait until the notes document is replicated to the DominoServer2 before I run the agent "RunWorkerOn2"?

Comment: The answer is that you don't have to wait. You can recode Worker to always look for the document on DominoServer1 instead of the current server. In order for that to work, will you have to change a security setting on DominoServer1. It's called the Trusted Servers setting. Information about it is here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/othr_serverdocumentsecuritytab_r.html. You would need to enter DominoServer2 and DominoServer3 into this field in the DominoServer1 server document. That tells Dominoserver1 to let the other servers validate the agent signature.

Comment: Thank you, the Trusted Servers setting is already set. But how will the recode of Worker for looking the specific document on DominoServer1 look like? Before I start any Agent, im able to handover the noteID to the agent. Do I have to handover the noteID in the end of the code of RunWorkerOn2 to Worker Agent, which makes always in the beginning of code a connection to DominoServer1?

Comment: By the way please also note, that if I run the code above (see my in my question) in console there is this error: DIIOP Server: Agent 'RunOnServer2' error: This database object is already open as D:\..(path of the db)..\ScheduledJobs.nsf